# Squid Proxy TCP_Miss all the time, not caching at all in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I've install Squid Proxy via `sudo apt-get install` squid on Ubuntu for a forward proxy

I've not modified any of the default settings in squid.conf apart from `http_access deny all` to `http_access allow all`

Now I've used this command `# tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log` to monitor the squid access logs in real time and I see that despite numerous different types of websites, static and dynamic, lots of images and static files, the results are still always the same.

Lots of `TCP_Miss` and barely two or three `TCP_Hits` I've also checked the size of Squid's spool and it's only `4.0K`

So I know now that Squid is not caching anything. Is there anyone able to help me out there with this? I've read almost every single article from google when searching for "Squid TCP_Miss" and "Squid not caching" but none of those worked for me.

Thanks